# Mean time to failure (MTTF) of coreless DC motor?

Tags: motor, dc-motor

What is a typical MTTF of a small coreless DC motor (e.g. 4x12mm) like the one seen here?

[image]

For a non-coreless 'toy' permanent magnet DC motor, the MTTF was shown to be in the 10s of hours at rated voltage, with MTTF decreasing exponentially as voltage was increased beyond spec: https://www.pololu.com/docs/0J11/all

However, [I have read](http://www.koshindenki.com/img/file/CL_TechnologyOvr_R3a_Std.pdf) that coreless DC motors can have longer commutator/brush life due to lower inductance.  Would it be reasonable to expect a coreless DC motor to have an MTTF of 500-1000 hours if the applied voltage was half the spec voltage?  Does continuous (i.e. multiple hours) operation wear down the brushes faster than shorter runs (in the minutes)?

This information has not been available from any of the vendors I have interacted with, so I guess my next step would be to buy 100 or so and test them.

Comment: Go to a vendor that provides the information. Those that don't can offer no guarantee on anything and are a waste of time and money. There will be exceptions of course BUT how can you tell which are the exceptions?

Comment: @Andyaka I guess my reasoning is that if it is not industry standard to determine/publish this information (e.g. due to typical application not needing it), then it doesn't necessarily mean the designs are not capable of providing what I want -- I would just have to test a large sample size.  There seems to be a big gap in price (<1$ vs $10+) for toy vs medical device motors, so I may have to 'make lemonade' in this case.

Comment: Radio Control Forums and I agree that a small coreless motor is cheap and has only a few hours of running life. They are made to hum-hum for short durations occasionally. The brushes are tiny and soon wear out or burn out. The bearings are garbage so the no load current is fairly high. The tiny brushes become blown fuses when the motor is stalled by something. EDIT: all my small brushless motors last forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would it be reasonable to expect a coreless DC motor to have an MTTF
>   of 500-1000 hours if the applied voltage was half the spec voltage?

lifespan is mainly determined by brush wear, which increases at higher rpm and higher current. Intermittent running is worse due to startup surge currents, but a lower duty increases the life of the motor by reducing its run time. Therefore it is difficult to give a MTTF because it depends on how the motor is operated. However you can get *some* idea from the intended application.

The most popular uses for small coreless motors are cell-phone vibrators and small r/c quadcopters ('drones'). Drone motors are designed to produce the most possible power at high rpm, so they have a short life. Vibrator motors work at lower rpm and current, but are trending towards higher power to get stronger vibration.

Typical no-load rpm is 40,000-80,000rpm, with smaller diameter motors generally running faster. At half voltage a DC motor will run at half speed, so lifespan should be dramatically improved if the load is light. However even with a light load a high power motor will draw relatively high current, so a drone motor is likely to have a shorter lifespan than a vibrator motor. A larger diameter motor may also have longer lifespan because the brushes and commutator can be larger and more robust, and a longer motor is usually more efficient (due to more copper in the 'active' part of the basket) so it draws less current for the same power output.

I am running 24V 7x16mm coreless motors on 7.4V, doing ~9000rpm and drawing 10-20mA. I pulled one apart after about 50 hours operation and the brush wear was almost imperceptible. Unfortunately all the sources for this particular motor seem to have dried up, as modern devices typically run on 3.7V or lower. However a few manufacturers (eg. [Namiki](http://www.namiki.net/product/dcmotor/coreless.html), [Citizen](http://www.citizen-micro.com/items/htmls/029-046.pdf)) still make higher voltage low speed coreless motors for industrial applications. These are expensive, but should last much longer than the 'generic' coreless motors used in toys etc.

Comment: I'm guessing the higher-end manufacturers you linked are significantly more expensive (they had 'contact us for quote')?  I was planning to use one of the typical 50 cent 3.7V motors, since I would prefer if motor cost is not more than $1 per, and I would also like to achieve ~10kRPM (usually ~1V) at typical uC voltages.  The usage will be more similar to vibration applications, except I will have a balanced load that will run for 30 minutes at a time.

Answer (score 1):

My initial answer is that I don't know the MTTF of the motor types you are describing, but you are not going to get anywhere near 500 - 1000 hours out of them.  Now, my reasoning for that statement.

Having experimented with a large number of coreless motors between 4mm and 12mm for model trains, the "cheap" (a.k.a. 50 cent) motors like you are suggesting generally have very cheaply made brushes compared to something like a Maxon or Faulhaber coreless motor.  I tested at least 10 random different ones about 10 years ago, running them only at half rated voltage and well below their stated maximum current, but in a model train locomotive, so they were under load, not just free-running on a workbench.  Not a single one could sustain even 20 hours of continuous running without burning the brushes down to nothing.  No way would I expect such a motor to survive 500 - 1000 hours.  Not a chance.

In sharp contrast, I have run Faulhaber and Maxon coreless motors under load (not beyond their stated maximum current) for hundreds of hours.

If you can relax your size constraint, you can definitely get 7mm or 8mm coreless motors that can run for hundreds of hours.  Maxon and Faulhaber both make motors in that size that you can get reasonably priced on the surplus market (i.e. eBay) these days. (I mean under $20 per motor)

And depending on your space constraints, it's not true that the non-coreless "toy" motors only last 10's of hours.  You won't find anything in the 4mm x 12mm range, but I have run lots of Mabuchi conventional armature, carbon brush motors that are in the rectangular size range of 10mm x 12mm x 15mm long for at least 100 hours without a problem.

Carbon brush motors can be very durable if the brushes are a decent size (say, at least 1/16" diameter).  The carbon can absorb and dissipate heat better than the relatively tiny metal finger brushes they put in those 50 cent coreless vibration motors.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a coreless dc motor is infinite if used correctly, if not it will last 500/1000 hours or less.